# passing a pandas dataframe into a function then perform calculation with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm passing a large dataframe into a function that I wrote to do some calculation with conditions, but Python is returning an error. I think it's because I'm checking if the data column equals a particular value then perform a calculation, otherwise perform another calculation.

I'm trying to calculate in pandas arrays instead of looping through each line of data and then calculating line by line due to the large dataset.

A subset of the data looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
myData = pd.DataFrame({'K':[810,820,825,830,840],'Type':
['C','C','P','P','C'],'S':[978,978,978,978,978],'R':
[0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05]})
```

The function that's reading in the dataframe is below:

```
def function(type,S,K,r):
    if type == 'C':
        calc = S / K * r
    elif type == 'P':
        calc = (S + r) / K - r * 10
    return calc
```

And I'm trying to pass myData into function by doing the following:

```
function(myData['Type'],myData['S'],myData['K'],myData['r'])
```

The error message is:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I think the error has something to do with the myData['Type'] and the condition if type == 'C'. Is there a way to work around this, or do I have to loop through dataset and calculate for each line?
Thanks.

Comment: Use `myData.apply(lambda x: function(x['Type'], x['S'], x['K'], x['R']), axis=1)` or `[function(*x) for x in zip(myData['Type'], myData['S'], myData['K'], myData['R'])]` or `[function(x['Type'], x['S'], x['K'], x['R']) for _, x in myData.iterrows()]`?

Comment: @Zero Thank you for your input. All three methods work! I'm new to Python and programming, do you mind explaining what the 2nd and 3rd methods mean?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use `np.select`:

```
condition = [myData.Type == 'C', myData.Type == 'P']

choiceList = [myData.S / myData.K * myData.R, (myData.S + myData.R) / myData.K - myData.R * 10]

np.select(condition,choiceList)
```

Output:

```
array([ 0.06037037,  0.05963415,  0.68551515,  0.67837349,  0.05821429])
```

Comment: Thank you for the input, this method works. However, my concern is that the "choiceList" calculates both values and stores in a list, then compared to the "condition" list. I'm new to Python and programming, but this approach seems consume lots of memory, am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

I  try by use `myData.groupby('Type')`:

```
a=myData.groupby('Type')
myData['calc']=a.get_group('C').S/a.get_group('C').K*a.get_group('C').R

myData['calc']=myData['calc'].fillna((a.get_group('P').S+a.get_group('P')
    .R)/a.get_group('P').K-a.get_group('P').R*10)


myData
```

The result show:

```
Out[149]:
    K    R       S  Type    calc
0   810 0.05    978 C   0.060370
1   820 0.05    978 C   0.059634
2   825 0.05    978 P   0.685515
3   830 0.05    978 P   0.678373
4   840 0.05    978 C   0.058214
```

Uder 50 reputations is painful for adding a comment!If you like it ,just accept it!